# Universal Coefficient Theorem - what kind of morphisms?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be an $R$-module, where $R$ is a P.I.D., and let $X$ be a topological space. We have the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow H_n(X) \otimes G \rightarrow H_n(X; G) \rightarrow \text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), G) \rightarrow 0.$$

The objects in this sequence are $R$-modules.

**Question:** Are the homomorphisms in this sequence $R$-module homomorphisms or just $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms?

**Remark:** Hatcher, Spanier, Google and the other references that I looked up do not explicitly say this, and it's not clear to me.

Comment: As an example, what can you say about $H_1(X;\mathbb{Q})$ as an abelian group, and as a vector space?

Comment: @Drew your question is rather vague, and I don't see how it helps. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The point is that $H_1(X;\mathbb{Q})\simeq H_1(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ both as abelian groups and as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space

Comment: @Drew but how do you know that? My question is precisely whether this isomorphism that you get (in this case because Tor is zero) is an isomorphism as groups or as vector spaces. I don't think that in general being isomorphic as groups implies being isomorphic as vector spaces. Just consider that there are additive functions of the reals into themselves that are **not** linear.

Comment: But here you know what the map $H_n(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Q})$ is - and you know (on the chain level) where the module structure is coming from

Comment: I think, if you go through the proof you see that all the homomorphisms are homomorphisms of $G$-modules.

Comment: $G$ is an $R$-module. What do you mean by $G$-module?

Comment: @JasonPolak sorry, I meant R-module. Fixing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the morphisms are $R$-module morphisms. This is very easy to see using some abstract nonsense. Everything here is functorial in $G$, i.e. if $f:G\to G'$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module morphism, the induced diagram

$$\begin{array}{c}
H_\ast(X)\otimes G & \rightarrow & H_\ast(X;G) & \rightarrow & Tor(H_{\ast-1}(X),G) \\
   \downarrow      &             &  \downarrow &             &  \downarrow \\
H_\ast(X)\otimes G' & \rightarrow & H_\ast(X;G') & \rightarrow & Tor(H_{\ast-1}(X),G')
\end{array}$$

commutes. Now set $G':=G$ and $f(g):=rg$ for some $r\in R$ and you will get that the maps commute with multiplication by elements of $R$: In other words the maps are $R$-module morphisms.

Comment: That's a nice way to see it. Exactly what I was looking for. I'll give the bounty once it becomes available. Thank you.